# Get week of month with Joda-Time

Tags: datetime, jodatime

Is it possible to parse a date and extract the week of month using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). I know it is possible to do it for the week of year but I cannot find how/if it is possible to extract the week of month.

Example: 2014-06_03 where 03 is the third week of this month

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String yearMonthWeekOfMonth = dt.toString("<PATTERN for the week of month>");
```

I have tried the pattern "yyyyMMW" but it is not accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current `joda-time` version doesn't support week of month, so you should use some workaround.
**1)** For example, you can use next method:

```
   static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM_'%d'");
   static String printDate(DateTime date)
   {
      final String baseFormat = FORMATTER.print(date); // 2014-06_%d 
      final int weekOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth() % 7;
      return String.format(baseFormat, weekOfMonth);
   }
```

Usage:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String dateAsString = printDate(dt);
```

**2)** You can use Java 8, because Java's API supports week of month field.

```
  java.time.LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM_W");
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, finally with SimpleDateFormat did the trick for me, but it is good to know that it is supported by Java 8

Comment: Correction for the first solution : `final  int weekOfMonth = (date.getDayOfMonth() / 7) + 1;`

Answer (score 6):

This option in Joda is probably nicer:

```
Weeks.weeksBetween(date, date.withDayOfMonth(1)).getWeeks() + 1
```

Comment: Just pay attention that if `date > then date.withDayOfMonth(1)` code above returns negative values, at least for `joda-time 2.9.1`, doesn't know is it bug or intended behaviour, but according to API it should be `..(start,end)`, `public static Weeks weeksBetween(ReadablePartial start,ReadablePartial end)`, http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html#weeksBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant, org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)

Comment: you can always do Weeks.weeksBefore(date1.isBefore(date2) ? date1 : date2, date1.isBefore(date2) ? date2 : date1)).getWeeks() + 1

Answer (score 1):

For the case you don't like calculations so much:

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date.toDate());
    int weekOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the start day of week is Monday then you can use it:

```
public int getWeekOfMonth(DateTime date){
    DateTime.Property dayOfWeeks = date.dayOfWeek();
    return (int) (Math.ceil((date.dayOfMonth().get() - dayOfWeeks.get()) / 7.0)) + 1;
}
```